# make mistake in setting IP

Tags: networking, ssh, interface, ip

I have a device that has Linux Ubuntu OS. I use SSH for connecting to it.
my Linux version is like below when typed `cat /proc/version` command:

```
Linux version 3.2.40-g996c4d7-dirty (sysmocom@vagrant-ubuntu-precise) (gcc version 4.6.3 20111117 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #1 PREEMPT Mon Oct 7 8:28:29 CEST 2013.
```

I change the IP setting with `vi` command (`vi /etc/network/interfaces`), but I made a mistake in writing the word "address". I typed it "adress".

Now I don't see the device in the network and I don't know what is it's IP.
How i can connect to it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you can connect to your machine anymore by any means, the nic adaptor does not have an ip in this state. 
You have to get to the console (physical monitor attached to the machine), login  and then correct the networking file.

Comment: How it is possible?I mean how can i see the files of this device?

Comment: @Ehsan I think mdalacu means the `/etc/network/interfaces` you mentioned in your question. Didn't you correct the mistake?

Comment: Remote you can not, you have to work from the affected computer and just corect /etc/network/interfaces file.

Comment: @Jacob my problem is that I can't remote to device and correcting the file.

Comment: @ mdalacu what's you mean?I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Then I think mdalacu is right, you have to correct it on the computer itself, not from remote.

Comment: You have to use the physical keyboard and monitor attached to the affected computer, login and correct your file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use netdiscover to get a list of local ip adresses. It gives you a list like:

```
 5 Captured ARP Req/Rep packets, from 5 hosts.   Total size: 300               
 _____________________________________________________________________________
   IP            At MAC Address      Count  Len   MAC Vendor                   
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 192.168.0.1     aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff    01    060   Sitecom Europe BV 
 192.168.0.101   aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff    01    060   Unknown vendor               
 192.168.0.104   aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff    01    060   Somedevice, INC.         
 192.168.0.116   aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff    01    060   Another Device
```

It is a command line application, run it by `sudo netdiscover`. If you run the command, it will offer you to install it if you haven't installed it before.

Comment: it's a good idea. but i don't know ip range of it.

Comment: @Ehsan you mean in your local network? It does not ask for it. It is on the local network isn't it?

Comment: @ Jacob yes,I attached my device to local network.
I was try to set  static ip for it and beacause of my mistake, i lost it in the network.

Answer (score 0):

from your question i assume this is your own network so If you have the MAC of this device , you may use software for sniffing the MACs on the network

Comment: I have the device MAC address but I dont't know any software that search the network for MAC address.

Comment: what os you use for your pc , and what is the type of that device , some brands have their own software for such situations

Comment: do you recommend any tools to find the mentioned MAC?please advise

Comment: You can use sudo arp-scan -l. Will got all mac address on lan.